# Adjective in "Ulysses" that means "existing in this world as opposed to an imagined one"

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

I came across this word in Joyce's *Ulysses*, but can't remember what it was. I only remember looking up the definition, which was something like "existing in this world as opposed to an imagined one." This makes it somewhat synonymous with "real," "actual," or "factual," but it's not any word that commonly appears in thesauri (or anywhere for that matter), so don't expect to find it in your average thesaurus. I've already looked through several. I believe it was a Latinate word, however. Anybody familiar with *Ulysses* know which word I'm referring to?

I'm something of a logophile and found this word quite lovely. I'm going crazy trying to remember it.

Comment: Do you mean the novel *Ulysses* by James Joyce or the poem *Ulysses* by Alfred Lord Tennyson? Or maybe a particular translation of the *Odyssey*?

Comment: Good question. I meant Joyce's *Ulysses*. I've edited the original post for clarification.

Comment: Perhaps something like ***sublunary***? That at least means the right thing, though I’ve no idea if it’s in _Ulysses_ or not.

Comment: @Janus That word occurs three times in the novel (I haven't read it, but the text is online).

Comment: Janus, that's it! *Sublunary*: "belonging to this world as contrasted with a better or more spiritual one." It's the "better or more spiritual" part that gives it nuance in context of the book's metaphysical themes. I'm amazed how quickly that was resolved. Thank you both for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My first thought was that it could be [***sublunary***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sublunary), which Oxford Dictionaries Online defines as:

> Belonging to this world as contrasted with a better or more spiritual one

That seems to be more or less exactly the meaning you are going for, and searching through the [Gutenberg Project online version](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/4300/4300-h/4300-h.htm) (with thanks to Andrew Leach’s comment to the question) shows that it appears thrice in *Ulysses*:

> Beneficent Disseminator of blessings to all Thy creatures, how great and universal must be that sweetest of Thy tyrannies which can hold in thrall the free and the bond, the simple swain and the polished coxcomb, the lover in the heyday of reckless passion and the husband of maturer years. But indeed, sir, I wander from the point. How mingled and imperfect are all our **sublunary** joys.
>
> Mr Bloom thoroughly acquiesced in the general gist of this though the mystical finesse involved was a bit out of his **sublunary** depth still he felt bound to enter a demurrer on the head of simple, promptly rejoining.
>
> Indubitably in consequence of the reiterated examples of poets in the delirium of the frenzy of attachment or in the abasement of rejection invoking ardent sympathetic constellations or the frigidity of the satellite of their planet. Did he then accept as an article of belief the theory of astrological influences upon **sublunary** disasters?

The origin of the word is fairly straightforward: it is from Latin *sublūnāris*, formed from *sub* ‘under’, *lūna* ‘moon’, and the suffix *-āris* denoting adjectives denoting ‘related to X’—so it’s ‘that which is related to what is under the moon’, literally. The spirit world is evidently considered to be, as it were, over the moon.

Comment: Bravo. The lunar connotation is especially suggestive, given the book's association between femininity (the moon being a traditional symbol of the feminine), fertility, and creativity. Joyce's wordplay never ceases to amaze. Thank you Janus.

Comment: @Damon Glad to help out—going crazy trying to remember a word is the most annoying state of being there is! Without looking into it any further, I would venture that the Latin word reflects some level of connotation between the Moon and femininity/fertility/childbirth, as personified (or perhaps rather deified) in the goddess Juno, who is associated with all four things.

Comment: Indeed, I see now that the word is more closely related to the meaning of "carnal" or "earthly" than to "factual." It would be interesting to know if *sublūnāris* has any Latin antonyms.

Comment: A direct antonym would of course be _supralūnāris_, but I'm not sure if that was ever really used…

Comment: OED also has all three (or six) of *supralunar(y), superlunar(y)*, and *translunar(y)* as English words, plus *circumlunar, cis-lunar, interlunar, novilunar, semilunar(y), presemilunar(y)* all more or less directly from Latin into English. It also has French-derived *demilune, interlune, novilune, perilune, plenilune/plenilunar, semi-lune*, and *clair-de-lune*. The verb *dislune* for uncrazying someone is a nonce-word.

Comment: "evidently considered to be, as it were, over the moon" -- specifically, in any sensible cosmology the spheres of the heavens are above/outside that of the moon (excepting the sphere of the moon, I suppose, which being level with the moon still is not sublunary) :-) Also possible Kabbalah connection, Yesod links Malkuth to everything else, which is the same point again. I'd guess the Latin isn't much inspired by Kabbalah, but Joyce's choice of words may have been.